# Enable PUT on WCF REST Api on IIS 6 (without .svc file)

Tags: wcf, http, iis, rest

On IIS 6 how can I allow the PUT operation on a WCF Rest API?

Since I don't have the .svc file (I added a route on global.asax to service class) I can't allow the put operation on the .svc extension on IIS 6.

Answer (score 3):

- Open the IIS Management console,
- Right click on your website in the sidebar and go to properties.
- Go to the "Home Directory" Tab
- Click on the "configuration" button
- Add a wildcard mapoping to your isapi.dll (you can copy and paste from the top window). Uncheck the "verify file exists" checkbox

Other solution suggest changing the verbs for a given extension, but if you don't have one thne this wildcard thing works.

There may be a better way of course but it works for us

Answer (score 1):

PUT verb for us would not work when calling the API via CURL for testing yet other verbs were ok.

- REST API
- Windows 2003 Server x64 standard edition
- IIS6
- .net 4.0 framework

For us the solution was:

- open MMC and connect to IIS6
- right click website and properties
- select home directory
- configuration
- select the file extension you are using
- EDIT
- Either "allow all verbs" or add "PUT" to the "Limit to" list.
- Apply

Hope that helps someone.

(please note i tried the WILDCARD suggestion below but did not resolve our issue)