# How to enable HTTP PUT on IIS 6?

Tags: asp.net, http, iis-6, http-put

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 web site that I am trying to deploy on a server running IIS 6.  Everything works OK, except I am getting an error when trying to make an HTTP `PUT` request to an *`.aspx`* page:

> Error Message: Path 'PUT' is forbidden.
>   Stack Trace:    at System.Web.HttpMethodNotAllowedHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

This is an ASP.NET 3.5 Forms application.  I have tried:

- Setting "All" Verbs for .aspx in IIS Mappings
- Setting "All" Verbs for .svc in IIS Mappings
- Adding a wildcard application map for 
  *`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll`*
- Adding "PUT" to the system.webServer -> handlers section in web.config

If anyone has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.

I have had no problems with the same site running on IIS 7.5, but unfortunately I am stuck with 6.0 in this case.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enable PUT on WCF REST Api on IIS 6 (without .svc file)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442514/enable-put-on-wcf-rest-api-on-iis-6-without-svc-file)

Comment: @Babak-Naffas As I stated in my question, I have already tried adding the aspnet_isapi.dll wildcard

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN Register Http Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

According to MSDN, you should register your verb in the httpHandlers section of your web.config instead of the System.WebServer handlers section because you're running IIS 6.0.